# XSD conditional logic and regex

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following part of my XML schema:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="aux_data">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="field_name" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="field_value" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

"field_name" could have one of three different values: payment_date, bank_acct, and amt_due. "field_value" has to match a different regex for each "field_name".

What would be an equivalent of the following Java code for this schema?

```
if(field_name.equals("payment_date")) {
   field_value.matches(/**regex*/);
}
else if(field_name.equals("bank_acct")) {
   field_value.matches(/**another regex*/);
}
```

I cannot use type xs:date, as I cannot have dashes in the date format, so I have to use xs:string.

Answer (score 1):

XSD 1.0 cannot express your constraints; XSD 1.1 can using assertions.

However, you're struggling because your XML design is too meta for XSD's constraint checking, which is anchored upon element names.

Rather than

```
<aux_data>
  <field_name>payment_date</field_name>
  <field_value>2017/09/18</field_value>
<aux_data>
```

use

```
<payment_date>2017/09/18</payment_date>
```

and similarly for `bank_acct` and `amt_due`.

If you change your XML design, you'll be able to express your constraints in XSD 1.0 quite naturally.

Comment: There are sometimes cases where a "meta" design pattern like this is appropriate (sometimes it makes conversion to and from other formats easier). But it's a design pattern that isn't well supported by XSD.